# extracting and changing data in a trx (xml) document

Tags: xml, vb.net, trx

I have a .trx file (a unit test result file) which is just xml inside and I want to read the file compare a few of the tags and change them as necessary and save the file again.

I found that VB.NET has a few tools to help so the first thing I do is load the document into an xml document which seems to work fine but I can't access any of the data I need. Right now I'm trying to access the attributes of the counters tag and change them after rerunning some of the tests.

So how do I do it?

this loads the file:

```
Dim Doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Doc.load("testFile.trx")
```

Attempted ways to access node:

```
Dim attribute As Integer = CInt(xmlTrxMasterDoc.SelectSingleNode("/TestRun/ResultSummary/Counters").Attributes(i).InnerText)

Dim node As XmlNode = xmlTrxMasterDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Counters")
Dim i As Integer = 1
node.Attributes.Item(i).InnerText
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun someattributes="" >
    <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
        <Counters total="115" executed="115" passed="110" error="0" failed="5" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
    </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "vb.net ||" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: got it. my first question sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document may help you: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301225

Also take a look at "Linq to xml"  that helps a lot: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/LINQ-to-XML-Programming-Using-Visual-BasicNET-2008/

Comment: Both links are dead for me. I know about Linq but what was the first link supposed to be about? ( I know its way back. I'm just asking in case. )

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net has XML Literals which makes it really easy to work with XML documents. The code below will give you the `total` attribute of the `Counters` node:

```
Dim X = <TestRun someattributes="">
            <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
                <Counters total="115" executed="115" passed="110" error="0" failed="5" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0"/>
            </ResultSummary>
        </TestRun>

Console.WriteLine(X.<ResultSummary>.<Counters>.@total)
```

Otherwise this should do what you're looking for:

```
Dim Doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
Doc.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "testFile.trx"))
Dim attribute = Doc.SelectSingleNode("//TestRun/ResultSummary/Counters").Attributes("total").Value
Console.WriteLine(attribute)
```

Comment: My code still fell over at the following line, because Doc is empty.
The xml literals works nicely though, how would you assign the xml from a file though?
    Dim attribute = Doc.SelectSingleNode("//TestRun/ResultSummary/Counters").Attributes("total").Value

Comment: In the above code, `X` is an `XElement` object. You can load it from disk by doing `XElement.Load(file)`.